# Why doesn't the Project Parameter get created when I Convert Deployment Model?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

We're upgrading our SQL Server 2012 SSIS packages to SQL Server 2019. The 2012 packages were created using the old package deployment model and an XML configuration file. We want to upgrade them to the project deployment model with project parameters. The initial upgrade from 2012 to 2019 came off without a hitch, but the deployment model change is proving more difficult.

For the sake of this question, we'll just look at one package.

I'm using VS2019 with the SSIS extension version 3.14. I created an SSIS project with SQL Server 2019 as the TargetServerVersion and imported one of the newly upgraded packages. I right click on the project, and select `Convert Deployment Model`. The `Integration Services Project Conversion Wizard` opens.

We accept the defaults on the first couple of pages, then we get to `Create Parameters`. We have a couple of connection string components and a file path. Nothing fancy.

[image]

We'll also take all the defaults on the `Configure Parameters` tab, and finish. And everything theoretically looks great:

[image]

But it's not great. We save and reopen the package, and it throws numerous errors, all related to missing parameters. For instance:

> The variable "$Project::ConfigurationEdrivePath" was not found in the Variables collection. The variable might not exist in the correct scope.

Looking at the `Variables` tab, the project parameter was inserted into the variable expression, as expected:

[image]

But the corresponding project parameters were not created. Not this one, nor any of the others, either:

[image]

I've tried it with the package open and with it closed. I've tried making the parameters required. All end up the same way. If we make them package parameters, instead of project parameters, they get created just fine, but most (all?) of our parameters will be at the project level, so that's not useful.

What am I missing?

Comment: Never used that feature. Could it be that the Project Conversion wizard is converting multiple packages and the final one doesn't have those project parameters?

Comment: @billinkc, in order to keep it clean, I only put one package in the project. Good thought, but no such luck.